# Why don't atoms with expanded

Tags: lewis-structure, formal-charge

My title may be confusing, so let me explain. Let's take the molecule SO2 for example...

[image]

Above, you can see that the Sulfur atom has 6 electrons from its original valence shell involved in bonding/in a lone pair. However, if you add up these bonds, the atom has 10 electrons, not 8 (which disobeys the octet rule). I was told this is because sulfur has access to the d orbital of electrons. That makes sense, but why does it not get a 2- charge if it is getting 2 more electrons in it's valence shell?

Thanks!

Will

Comment: It is not getting any extra electrons. Why would it? Where from?

Comment: If this puzzles you, you can remove one of the two bonds between S and O and put it entirely on the oxygen atom which becomes negatively charged. The sulfur atom, having lost one electron, will then become positively charged, but it is now surrounded by 8 electrons.

Answer (score 0):

This is because covalent bonds are when electrons are SHARED BETWEEN THE ATOMS, not all given to 1 atom (that's an ionic bond). The sulfur may gain a *partial* charge (positive in this case), because more electronegative atoms hold electrons closer, but never a full charge.